# java.awt.Headless Exception in JFilechooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

This code keeps giving `java.awt.HeadlessException` and I don't know why.
I'm using Netbeans 7.4
This code used to work before adding a file chooser.
I used to give an absolute path.
Code:

```
JButton open = new JButton();
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\theOPOne\\Desktop"));
fc.setDialogTitle("Choose path !");
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
if (fc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   /*...*/
}

Document document=new Document(); 
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath())); 
document.open(); 
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello world this is my first PDF"));
document.close();
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I mean "I don't know why"

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: what must i do to do it ?